# How to set consumer priority using MassTransit and RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

MassTransit exposes functions for adding queue and exchange arguments, but I cannot find anything similar for the consumer.

I would like to be able to set the priority of consumers (x-priority argument) per the RabbitMQ documentation here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-priority.html

Is that possible using MassTransit?

Comment: I just pushed this to develop, should be in the next release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to RabbitMQ documentation:

> Set the x-priority argument in the basic.consume method to an integer
>   value. **Consumers which do not specify a value have priority 0**.
>   Larger numbers indicate higher priority, and both positive and
>   negative numbers can be used.

When you setup consumer you can use ConsumerPriority in this case to set a lower priority

```
_busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    IRabbitMqHost host = cfg.Host(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQHost"]), h =>
    {
        h.Username(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQUsername"]);
        h.Password(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQPassword"]);
    });

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "Audit", e =>
    {
        e.PrefetchCount = 2;
        e.ConsumerPriority = -1;
        e.Consumer<AuditConsumer>();
    });
});
```

[image: Rabbit Consumer]

Answer (score 2):

It should be easy enough to add this to MT, I'll create an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Is this added to MT in the meanwhile?